# Not Comprehending How Modulus Works (Eclipse)

Tags: java, modulus

I'm just starting an introduction tutorial to Java and already have a question about what (seems to me) as odd behaviour. Can someone please clarify how I'm looking at this tool incorrectly?

why does this not output odd numbers:

```
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            if ( i % 2 != 0){
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
            ++i;  ++j;
            if (j >= 10){
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
            }
        }
```

But this does even numbers:

```
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            if ( i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
            ++i;  ++j;
            if (j >= 10){
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
            }
        }
```

Even something like this does not work:

```
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            if ( i % 2 > 0){
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
            ++i;  ++j;
            if (j >= 10){
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice in each iteration of the loop; remove one of the `i++` expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` twice each loop -- once in the `for` loop itself, and once in the middle of the body.

The end result is that `i` is itself only even (0, 2, 4, ...) when you get to `if ( i % 2 != 0){`.

Remove the in-body increment of `i`; only increment in the `for` loop itself.  Change

```
++i;  ++j;
```

to

```
++j;
```

Comment: WOW.. that was incredibly shortsighted of me. Thank you all for the clarification. I'll click first answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are incrementing `i` twice, first in your `for`, second between your `if`'s. Thus, your `i` loops through even numbers only. Remove the second increment and it will work as you expect.

At the same time your `j` is incremented only once, so you should observe 10 numbers per line.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that "i++" appears twice in each loop iteration, so only every other value of I (I.e, even numbers) are ever considered. Remove the I++ from the body of the loop.